# Substitute for CONTAINS function in QUICK SIGHT

Tags: sql, function, tableau-api, amazon-quicksight, sql-query-store

What is the `Substitute/alternate` function for `CONTAINS` function in Amazon Quicksight. Or any function that can be used in the backend (in Redshift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `locate`. If a substring is not contained in a string, `locate` returns 0

```
locate(expression, substring, start)
```

[**Documentation**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/locate-function.html)